# Stream.filter based on javax.validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java-stream

I'm using Spring Boot. I know there is a `@Valid` annotation you can use on top of methods so it throws an `Exception` if it's not valid, but I don't want to throw an exception, I just want to ignore the invalid objects.

Let's say I have this model class:

```
public class User {
 
    @NotNull
    private String name;
 
    @AssertTrue
    private boolean working;
 
    @Size(min = 10, max = 200)
    private String aboutMe;

    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    private String email;
}
```

And this Stream:

```
Stream<User> stream = getUsers();
```

How can I filter based on the `javax.validation` annotations this class has?

```
stream.filter(u -> isValid(u));
```

Comment: `javax.validation.Validator userValidator = ...; stream.filter(u -> userValidator.validate(u).isEmpty())`

Comment: you want to ignore the exceptions then don't `@Valid`ate the object..otherwise handle the exception using a mapper to transform into a meaningful response.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like spring won't be helpful here, but you still can do that.

This `@Valid` annotation processing implementation is basically in integration with  project [Hibernate Validator](https://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/) (Don't get confused with the name, it has nothing to do with Hibernate ORM ;) )

So you could create the engine and validate "manually".

An example of using the validation engine:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
validator = factory.getValidator();

User user = ...
Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = validator.validate( user );
```

As you see, the Result of the validation in hibernate validator is not an exception (this is something that spring has added on top to better integrate with web mvc flow) but rather a set of "validation constraint violations". So basically is this set is not empty, there is at least one validation error so that you could filter it out.

I believe wrapping the this logic into filter is not that interesting once you're familiar with the foundations...